# Submodular monotone functions

Tags: matroids

A few definitions:

A Submodular function $ f:2^E \rightarrow R $ is a function that satisfies the following two equivalent definitions:

- for every $ S,T\subseteq E: f(S) + f(T) \geq f(S\cup T)+f(S\cap T) $
- for every $ S,T\subseteq E $ with $ S\subseteq T $ and for every $ x\in E\setminus T : f(S\cup \{x\})-f(S)\geq f(T\cup\{x\}) - f(T) $

A monotone submodular function is a submodular functions such that for every $ S,T \subseteq E $ with $ S\subseteq T : f(T)\geq f(S)  $ . We also define $ f(\emptyset) = 0 $.

Show that, for any $ S,T\subseteq E : f(T)\leq f(S) + \sum_{e_i\in T-S}(f(S\cup\{e_i\})-f(S))  $ where $f$ is a submodular monotone function . I've tried induction but got no where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(S \cup \{e_i\})+f(S \cup \{e_j\} ), e_i,e_j \in T-S$. It is obvious that $e_i,e_j \notin S $.
So, $$f(S \cup \{e_i\})+f(S \cup \{e_j\} ) \geq f(S \cup \{e_i,e_j\})+f(S)$$
Extending it to three terms,
$f(S \cup \{e_i\})+f(S \cup \{e_j\} )+f(S \cup \{e_k\}) \geq f(S\cup\{e_i,e_j\})+f(S\cup \{e_k\}) + f(S) \geq f(S \cup\{e_i,e_j,e_k\}) +2f(S)$

Suppose $|T-S| = n$.
Then,
$$\sum_{i \in T-S} f(S\cup \{e_i\}) \geq f(S \cup \{\cup e_i\}) + (n-1)f(S)$$
$$\sum_{i \in T-S} (f(S\cup \{e_i\})-f(S)) \geq  f(S \cup \{\cup_{i\in T-S} e_i\}) -f(S)$$
$$f(S)+\sum_{i \in T-S} (f(S\cup \{e_i\})-f(S)) \geq  f(S \cup \{\cup_{i\in T-S} e_i\}) $$
Note that $$f(S \cup \{\cup_{i\in T-S} e_i\}) = f(S\cup T)$$

$$f(S)+\sum_{i \in T-S} (f(S\cup \{e_i\})-f(S)) \geq  f(S \cup T)\geq f(T)$$

There you go!!

Comment: Sorry, computer broke :) Thanks for your answer